# Looping over bits in C

Tags: c

I'm a C newbie, I want to store input bits to an output array according to the below procedure.

```
input           MSB                  LSB MSB                  LSB MSB              
[169,48,0] =     1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1   0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The program should loop over the input data to find- in which byte the start index is present and extract the bits from start index till the end index and store it in the output[ ]. As an example my start index is 4 and it is present in input[0], my end index is 13. So I need to extract from bit position 4 to 13 and place it in output[ ].

What I meant when I said bit position 4 to 13 is that - I need bits[4 - 7] = {0 1 0 0 1} from input[0] and bits[8 - 13] = {1 1 0 0 0 0} from input[1]

```
expected
output
[9, 48,0] =     0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I tried to program in C but unfortunately I wasn't successful, the looping over bits is through LSB to MSB. I need to loop over 1st byte and continue to the next byte and repeat till the byte index where the end position is present.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char input[3] = {169,48,0};
    unsigned char output[3]= {0};
    int i, start = 4, end = 13;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        output[i] = (input[i] >> (start)) & ((1u << (end)) -1u);
        printf("%u\n",output[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program loops over all 3 input bytes and stores from bit index 4 to end index of that particular byte i.e 7.

```
output
[10, 3, 0] =     0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I want to check whether my start index is present in input[0] or input[1] or . . . input[n], copy and store from start index to end index(that may be present in any byte position) as per the **expected output** shown in the beginning.

I would be greatfull if you could correct the program logic as I'm new to C.

Comment: Similar [recently asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859951/copy-a-byte-from-source-to-destination-with-a-start-index-and-a-end-index).

Comment: Which ever end of the array you consider bit 0 to be, I can't figure out the expected output. If bit 0 is the LSB of the byte on the right, then bits 3-11 are all `0` and the output should be all `0`. If bit 0 is the LSB of the byte on the left, I still can't figure it out because output bit 0 is `1` and you said you ignore that bit.

Comment: If the number of bits you want to extract _is always eight_ (as in your example), this problem is reminiscent of calculating an 8-bit CRC. But I think you want to move an _arbitrary_ number of bits - is that correct?

Comment: Some variation of [this](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html##SelectPosFromMSBRank)

Comment: @DavidCollins No, it's not 8bits always.I need to extract some arbitrary number of bits.

Comment: @WeatherVane input[0] = 169 = {1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1} and input[1] = 48 = {0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0}. What I meant when I said bit position 3 to 11 is that - I need bits[3 - 7] = {0 1 0 0 1} from input[0]  and bits[8 - 11] = {0 0 1 1} from input[1].

Comment: Please improve the question, with an edit, to make it clear where bit 0 is.

Comment: Re your comment: bits 3 to 7 (actually 7 to 3) of `input[0]` are `10101`. You are counting from the wrong end (bits 4 to 0) with `01001`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have edited my question now and hope it's clear.

Comment: @shannon: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You are numbering bits from MSB to LSB for the input, but how do you pack the bits into the output? The expected output should be `0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 - 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`, not `0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  -  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0`

Comment: @shannon each byte represents two 4-bit *nibble*. You have a high-nibble (which appears to be your `bits[4-7]`) and a low-nibble (`bits[0-3]`). So you appear to simply want the high nibble of your byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the forum.

> I would be greatfull if you could correct the program logic as I'm new to C.

Here's a tentative effort. Your main logic is in the following line:

```
output[i] = (input[i] >> (start)) & ((1u << (end)) -1u);
```

This is easier to analyze by simplifying it to the following (and using a temporary `unsigned char` variable `tmp`):

```
tmp = input[i] >> start; // (1)
tmp &= (1u << end) - 1u; // (2)
// etc.
```

It is not clear to me precisely what you are trying to do here. I believe what you *should* be trying to do is extracting `8-start` bits from `input[i]` and `start` bits from `input[i+1]` and placing a logical OR of these values (appropriately shifted) in a temporary variable. If this is so, then my suggestions are the following.

In the first line (1) you are shifting the wrong direction: it should be

```
tmp = input[i] << start;
```

The next line (2) is not accomplishing anything. (You are effectively AND'ing with zero.) Also, you should be using | rather than &, and the second operand should be a selection of bits (appropriately shifted) from the next byte.

```
tmp |= input[i+1] >> (8-start);
```

This, then, is the *extraction* stage. Next would be the *insertion* stage in the output stream. There are more nuances not discussed above but that gives the general idea. (See below for an implementation which handles more details.)

> I want to check whether my start index is present in input[0] or input[1] or . . . input[n]

For this use

```
int idx = start / 8; // byte index
int offset = start % 8; // bit position within byte
```

**P.S.** Your original question indicated that the offset of the extracted bits could be different in the output stream than in the input stream. Your edits hide that fact, but the implementation below allows for this possibility (a 'transposition').

#### Possible implementation

```
void transpose_bits(unsigned char *a, unsigned char *b, int start, int end, int dest, size_t array_len) {
    unsigned char tmp = '\0', tmp2 = '\0';
    int offset = 0, idx = 0, len = 0, next_bits = 0;
    char bitmask = 0x80;

    len = end - start;
    while (len > 0) {
        // Single pass - transpose up to 8 bits ...
        tmp = tmp2 = '\0';

        // Determine the byte index and offset in the input byte array.
        idx = start / 8;
        offset = start % 8;
        tmp = a[idx] << offset;
        next_bits = offset + len - 8;
        if (next_bits < 0) {
            // Don't even need all of current byte  => remove trailing bits ...
            tmp &= bitmask >> (len - 1);
        } else if (next_bits > 0) {
            // Need to include part of next byte ...
            tmp2 = a[idx + 1] & (bitmask >> (next_bits - 1));
            tmp |= tmp2 >> (8 - offset);
        }

        // Determine byte index and offset in output byte array
        idx = dest / 8;
        offset = dest % 8;
        b[idx] |= tmp >> offset;
        b[idx + 1] |= tmp << (8 - offset);
        // Update start position and length for next pass ...
        if (len > 8) {
            len -= 8;
            dest += 8;
            start += 8;
        } else
            len -= len;
    }
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
// Extract bits: 'start' and 'dest' are the same.
transpose_bits(input, output, 4, 13, 4, 3); // Assume arrays are of length '3'

// Transpose bits: 'start' and 'dest' not the same.
transpose_bits(input, output, 4, 13, 10, 3);
```

**Notes**:

- The `char[]` arrays *must be unsigned* (as you have correctly chosen) - as the right shift operator works differently with signed values.
- You should check the bounds of the arrays (comparing `idx` against `array_len`); I have skipped that here for brevity
- Each iteration in the `while()` loop of the `transpose_bits()` function can handle up to 8 bits. By using multiple passes, it can handle an arbitrary number.

Comment: This helps. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately I cannot upvote this answer as I donot have enough reputation.

Comment: @shannon: No problem. I appreciate the feedback.